# How do I control the streaming frame rate of ffmpeg?

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, udp

I am using ffmpeg to stream video:

```
ffmpeg -i $file -f mpegts udp://hostname:port
```

On another machine, I am using VLC to play the output stream.
The problem I have is that VLC is playing the stream in a rate of 48 fps (instead of 24 fps).

I tried adding the `-r 24` option but it seems to have no effect on the output.

How can I control ffmpeg output rate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer for this:
simply add the `-re` flag before the input.

From the ffmpeg documentation:
`-re` Read input at native frame rate. Mainly used to simulate a grab device.